# How to use InteliJ settings repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up the IntelliJ Settings Repository.  My goal is for our whole development team to use a common set of settings.  But if understand correctly, anyone can just override the repo with their own settings by doing an Override Remote.   That would sort of defeat the purpose of having a team standard.  I want to set it up so that only certain people can change the repo.

I looked into the read-only repo, but that doesn't seem to work unless you already have a primary repo.  And it's not clear exactly what settings are saved in main repo as opposed to what settings you can retrieve from the read-only repos

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar request, please feel free to vote and comment:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185875

For now, you can setup own Settings repository and then add a repository that will contain settings for your team as "Read-only source".

Settings that are shared via "read-only sources" are those that have own folders under "[Configuration](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)" except "options" folder.